# Why gerund in this case

Tags: gerunds

> Glasgow post-punk six-piece Kaputt aren’t strangers to directing their explosive energy.

Why *directing* and not *to direct*?

Is it because it is an expression such as to be opposed to verbing or to be addicted to verbing  (be + adjective + to + verbing) but strangers is a name not an adjective?

Answer (score 2):

It's an idiom [be no stranger to sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-no-stranger-to-sth) which takes a noun (phrase).

<strike>In this particular case, the gerund *directing their explosive energy* plays that nominal role better than its to-infinitive counterpart*.</strike>

*We shouldn't even touch on the to-infinitive use here because the particle *to* is a part of the idiom.

> Glasgow post-punk six-piece Kaputt aren’t strangers to [what?].

> Glasgow post-punk six-piece Kaputt aren’t strangers to [directing their explosive energy].

Comment: why it plays that nominal role better than its to infinitive counterpart directing is not  a noun

Comment: @user5577 Halfway through the answer I realised there can't be a to-infinitive here because *to* is being the part of the expression "be a stranger to" and you can't syntactically make "be a stranger to to direct" work. The question then might be "bare infinitive vs gerund" but, since the limited application of the former, the choice is obvious.

Comment: @user5577 to answer your comment edit, gerund, by definition, [is a verb used as a noun](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)